# Emacs 24.3 corrupt ELPA

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs, elpa

I am using emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12. I installed the auto-complete package through the emacs built-in package manager, and it mostly worked. The quick help feature was however missing. I found this thread https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/65 descibing the same problem, so tried to copy the .el files from here, into the auto-complete directory created by the package manager. Now nothing works, and the package manager says:
 auto-complete is a deleted package.
 Status: Deleted.

I can't remove it, or reinstall it... Any help is appreciated. Also help on how to fix the quick help feature :D

Comment: Also I have to add that I am a linux noob.

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the folder inside the ELPA directory and then re-opening Emacs?

Comment: As a continuation of @lawlist, this is normally a sub-directory of `~/.emacs.d/` directory.

Comment: Deleting the folder ~./emacs.d/elpa/ , and then reinstalling the add-on worked. Thank you. There is however still the issue of auto-complete not showing quick help.